# Bounded Linear Operator (to show well-defined)

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $k:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ be measurable with respect to 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume that there are finite real constants $c_1,c_2$ such that

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert k(x,y) \right\vert dy\leq c_1$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert k(x,y) \right\vert dx\leq c_1$ for almost all $y\in\mathbb{R}$

Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$. Define $(Kf)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(x,y)f(y)dy$ for any $f\in L^p (\mathbb{R})$. Show that $K$ defines a bounded linear operator from $L^p (\mathbb{R})$ into itself, with $\left\Vert K\right\Vert\leq c_z^{1/q}c_2^{1/p}$. Here $q=p/(p-1)$ if $1<p<\infty$, $1/q=0$ if $p=1$ and $1/q=1$ if $p=\infty$.

To show that $Kf(x)$ is defined for almost all $x$, the proof is as below:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert k(x,y)f(y) \right\vert dy$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert k(x,y)\right\vert^{1/p}\left\vert f(y)\right\vert \left\vert k(x,y)\right\vert^{1/q}dy$

$\leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert k(x,y)\right\vert\left\vert f(y)\right\vert^pdy)^{1/p}\cdot (\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert k(x,y)\right\vert dy)^{1/q}$

$\leq c_1^{1/q}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert k(x,y)\right\vert\left\vert f(y)\right\vert^pdy)^{1/p}$

Thus $Kf(x)$ is defined for almost all $x$.

What I do not understand here is how the last line of the inequality shows that $Kf(x)$ is well defined. I am a bit confused here because the upper bound contains an integral.

Appreciate if anyone can explain to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another step. Integrating with respect to $x$, we see that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |Kf(x)|^{p}\,dx &\leq c^{p/q}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|k(x,y)||f(y)|^{p}\,dy\Big)\,dx\\
& \leq c_{1}^{p/q}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|k(x,y)|\,dx\Big)|f(y)|^{p}\,dy\\
&\leq c_{1}^{\frac{p}{q}}c_{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(y)|^{p}\,dy.
\end{align*}
Thus, $||Kf||_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})} \leq c_{1}^{\frac{1}{q}}c_{2}^{\frac{1}{p}}||f||_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R})}$ and hence $|Kf(x)| < \infty$ a.e and therefore well defined.

Comment: I see. So it seems to me that the "well defined" comes from the fact that the linear operator is bounded. Am I right to say that if I can show boundedness then I have well-defined?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Great! this is very helpful. Appreciate it.